# How can i join different filtered areas in 1 table

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I'm trying to find logistic company and cargo company combined performances from a table named orders. I write a working code but it is working slowly, i wanted it to work faster.

The working code is ;

```
'SELECT 
a.*,
b.number_of_order_lost_or_damaged,
c.number_of_order_lost_tracking FROM
(SELECT 
    logistic_partner,
        cargo_partner,
        round(AVG(DATEDIFF(date_delivered, date_add)),2) as time_spent_in_delivery
FROM
    orders
WHERE
    status IN (6)
GROUP BY logistic_partner , cargo_partner) a
    JOIN
(SELECT 
    logistic_partner,
        cargo_partner,
        COUNT(id) AS number_of_order_lost_or_damaged
FROM
    orders
WHERE
    status IN (8)
GROUP BY logistic_partner , cargo_partner) b USING (logistic_partner , cargo_partner)
    JOIN
(SELECT 
    logistic_partner,
        cargo_partner,
        COUNT(id) AS number_of_order_lost_tracking
FROM
    orders
WHERE
    status IN (10)
GROUP BY logistic_partner , cargo_partner) c USING (logistic_partner , cargo_partner);'
```

Not working code is

```
'SELECT 
o.logistic_partner,
o.cargo_partner,
round(AVG(DATEDIFF(a.date_delivered, a.date_add)),2) as time_spent_in_delivery,
count(b.id),
count(c.id) FROM orders o
    JOIN orders a on a.id=o.id and a.status = 6
    JOIN orders b on o.id=b.id and b.status = 8 
    JOIn orders c on c.id=o.id and c.status = 10
GROUP BY logistic_partner , cargo_partner;'
```

But those are working seperately :

```
'SELECT 
o.logistic_partner,
o.cargo_partner,
round(AVG(DATEDIFF(a.date_delivered, a.date_add)),2) as time_spent_in_delivery FROM orders o
    JOIN orders a on a.id=o.id and a.status = 6
GROUP BY logistic_partner , cargo_partner;'
```

or

```
SELECT 
o.logistic_partner,
o.cargo_partner,
count(b.id) FROM orders o
    JOIN orders b on o.id=b.id and b.status = 8 
GROUP BY logistic_partner , cargo_partner;
```

What could be the problem ?

Comment: This is an unclear bunch fragments. What is your 1 question? PS Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. PS [mre]

Comment: It'd be much easier to help if you put together a small [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That means A) posting the table structure (CREATE TABLE ....) B) sample data (INSERT statemetns). Not the entire table's worth of data, just enough rows to demonstrate the desired result C) The expected results.  Use tools like http://sqlfiddle.com/ with it's "Text to DDL" feature and/or https://dbfiddle.uk/ to help

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS A "basically" or "essentially" or "in other words" etc that isn't accompanied by a clear, precise & full description just means "unclearly" and/or "it is false that".

Comment: @SerkanGül - Here's what we mean by a minimal example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a5780f57983f0b0dfea6fe29c755f01b  You can use the "Markdown" link to generate formatted code you can paste directly into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you don't need any of those derived tables. Using conditional aggregation should produce the same result. For example:

```
SELECT logistic_partner
      , cargo_partner
      , ROUND(AVG(IF(status = 6, DATEDIFF(date_delivered, date_add), NULL)),2) AS time_spent_in_delivery
      , SUM( IF( status = 8, 1, 0) ) AS number_of_order_lost_or_damaged
      , SUM( IF( status = 10, 1, 0) ) AS number_of_order_lost_tracking
FROM  orders
GROUP BY logistic_partner
       , cargo_partner
```

Comment: @philipxy - Could you explain why you removed the "how to improve" content from the post? Just wondering.. Is this a new policy?

Comment: Content that is social interaction or not part of the answer doesn't belong in posts. This has always been policy. See the help or google with 'site:' at [help], [meta] & [meta.se]. Also unclear posts should be closed & commented on to request editing for clarification, not answered with guesses.

Comment: That's not my understanding, but I'll choose to leave it to avoid starting a silly rollback war.  Anyway, in future, it'd be more helpful to point to a specific post or mention in the docs backing that up, not just "general" help links :-)

Comment: *".. unclear posts should be closed & commented on to request editing for clarification, not answered with guesses.."* Its a balance IMO.  Agreed, some questions are too ambiguous and shouldn't be answered. Others, can be salvaged by giving new members a little a little extra help and guidance. Try and encourage and show them how to improve posts now and in future.

Comment: From [the FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303219/3404097): "Remove all noise  In addition to salutations, signatures, valedictions, and taglines, anything in a post that doesn't pertain to the question itself is considered noise." I'd agree that's not so clear re "pertain to the question itself". I don't quickly see a quote about noise including what belongs in a comment, like how the site works or requests for clarification. But from participating at [meta] I believe the intended "pertain" is to the question that is asked, not (meta) statements re asking it.

Comment: PS For whatever light it sheds: If an answer post contains only comment content, it is "not an answer" when flagging. Considering such answer post content as not part of answering the question asked & not belonging is at least consistent with that. Bye.

Comment: Thanks for the followup. I've always considered noise to be stuff *totally* unrelated to the question at hand. Tips to new members on question posting are relevant IMO, but agreed it can be subjective. Over and out.